# SQL / Presto error: TYPE_MISMATCH:Left side of logical expression must evaluate to a boolean (actual: varchar)

Tags: sql, presto, mismatch

I'm trying to match all active ***subscription*** statuses with shipping data from the ***customers*** table with the total charges & refunds from the ***charges*** table.
The error is from lines 29:88, or the 2nd "group by" after c.shipping_address_city. This issue does not occur with the first "group by" part of the query, which I copied & pasted into the second select statement.
When I got reduced the "group by" fields to only c.email or. c.id, I got an aggregate error:

```
active_customer_plans as (

  select c.email, c.id as customer_id, c.shipping_name, c.name, c.shipping_address_line1, c.shipping_address_line2, 
    c.shipping_address_city, c.shipping_address_state, c.shipping_address_postal_code, c.shipping_address_country, sum(charges.amount) as total_charges, 
    sum(charges.amount_refunded) as total_refunds
  from subscriptions sub
    left join charges on sub.customer_id = charges.customer_id
    left join customers c on sub.customer_id = c.id
  where sub.status in ('active', 'past_due')
  group by c.email, c.id, c.shipping_name, c.name, c.shipping_address_line1, c.shipping_address_line2, 
    c.shipping_address_city, c.shipping_address_state, c.shipping_address_postal_code, c.shipping_address_country
  

  union all

  -- including subscriptions migrated from vhx existing as trialing
  -- and excluding paused subscriptions
  select c.email, c.id as customer_id, c.shipping_name, c.name, c.shipping_address_line1, c.shipping_address_line2, 
    c.shipping_address_city, c.shipping_address_state, c.shipping_address_postal_code, c.shipping_address_country, sum(charges.amount) as total_charges,
    sum(charges.amount_refunded) as total_refunds, 'active (migrated_trialing)' as status
  from subscriptions sub
    left join charges on sub.customer_id = charges.customer_id
    left join customers c on sub.customer_id = c.id
  where sub.status in ('trialing')
  group by c.email, c.id, c.shipping_name, c.name, c.shipping_address_line1, c.shipping_address_line2, 
     c.shipping_address_city, c.shipping_address_state, c.shipping_address_postal_code, c.shipping_address_country
  
    and exists (
      select sub_meta.subscription_id
      from subscriptions_metadata sub_meta
      where sub.id = sub_meta.subscription_id
        and sub_meta.key = 'zype_migration'
        and sub_meta.value = 'true'
    )
    and not exists (
      select sub_meta.subscription_id
      from subscriptions_metadata sub_meta
      where sub.id = sub_meta.subscription_id
        and sub_meta.key = 'zype_status'
        and sub_meta.value = 'paused'
    )


  -- excluding subscriptions migrated from vhx existing as trialing
  -- and excluding paused subscriptions

)
select status as subscription_status,
    email as customer_email,
  customer_id,
  shipping_name,
  name,
  shipping_address_line1,
  shipping_address_line2,
  shipping_address_city,
  shipping_address_state,
  shipping_address_postal_code,
  shipping_address_country,
  total_charges,
  total_refunds
from active_customer_plans

order by 1, 2
```

Comment: your `and exists` and `and not exists` clauses are part of the where clause, they need to go before the group by.